# Not show side menu on some panels

Tags: html, intel, jqmobi, appframework, jqui

Is there a way to not to use a side menu on some of the panels, on Intel's App Framework 2.0 UI? I have a side menu defined through a `<nav>` tag, but I want to display it just on certain panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a different nav per panel, you can use the "nav" data attribute:

```
<nav id="nav1"> ... </nav>
<nav id="nav2"> ... </nav>

<div id="content">
    <div id="panel1" class="panel" data-nav="nav1"> ... </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel" data-nav="nav2"> ... </div>
</div>
```

It'll switch between the two navs as you switch between panels. Note that the first  in the markup/DOM becomes the default unless you specify `data-nav="none"` which will "hide" the nav for that panel. The problem I ran into is if you're on a tablet or larger, the media queries will still fill the space where the nav is with a blue column.

You'll have to disable that part in javascript by using the `$.ui.disableSideMenu();` function call (you can restore it with `$.ui.enableSideMenu();`).

You can also use the data attributes to affect which footer and header show on a per panel basis. Meanwhile you can leave those attributes out for panels that will use the defaults.

http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_panels

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the option like, `$.ui.disableSideMenu();` or `$.ui.slideSideMenu=false;` or `data-nav="none"` on the panels you don't want it to see the side panel.

Answer (score 1):

use `data-nav="none"` on the panels you don't want it to appear.